how to properly set the value of a textField through a button
i am trying to make a simple calculator, one of my first java projects, and i seem to have an issue of my textField not updating when i have a button set up to change the value of it.
I attempted with an event handler for my buttons
public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource()==button){
            String number = button.getText();
            
            equation.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            
        }
    }

for the buttons that I have this is what i have added for the event listener
for (int i = 7; i <=9; i++){
            Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(i));
            button.setId("button");
            button.setOnAction(this::handle);
            buttons1.getChildren().add(button);
        }

i have four for loops with 4 Hbox's to set up the button layout, however all of the for loops are the same, bar the numbers used in the for loops.

What is the button of event.getSource()==button It must be a field, which is unrelated to the button you are creating. Why even have that test at all though?

button in the for loop is a local variable that exists only in the body of the for loop, hence it cannot be the same button as in method handle, hence the if condition, in method handle, is always false. You can safely assume that event.getSource() returns a Button object so just cast it, i.e. Button b = (Button) event.getSource(); By the way, have you read [ask]? Looks to me that you have not, otherwise you would have posted a [mcve].

Related calculator example.

Your handler should look more like the following.
public void handle(ActionEvent event)
{
    Button tempButton = (Button)event.getSource();
    
    equation.appentText(tempButton.getText());    
}

I typed this directly, so there may be errors.
